# Can we fix the size of split screens in android in multi window mode ?

Tags: android

Can we fix the size of split screens in android in multi window mode So that the screen are not movable

Comment: _One line question is not valid here in SO._

Answer (score 0):

Not in the N Developer Preview 3. I would be rather surprised if they offered that feature in the future, but I cannot rule that out.